# Accurev: promote without specifying issue?

Tags: accurev

Is it possible to promote a file without specifying an issue number?

Related to that question, I see some files which have histories for which the column "Issues" is blank.  How does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Promoting against and issue is an option, rather than a requirement. An AccuRev depot does not have an AccuWork schema until an administrator creates one. Even then, this does not automatically require promoting to an issue. Within the Accuwork schema, this feature can be enabled using the Change Packages tab.

Answer (score 1):

To your second point "... some files which have histories for which the column "Issues" is blank. How does that happen?"

1. If you've changed over from non-Issue based development to Issue based development and have not associated the files, those with active or (member) status, with Issues, that column will be blank.
2. **More likely** some one promoted foo.c to Issue 15. Then opened up Issue 15 and removed foo.c from the Issue. In this case the column will be blank too.

The solution is to find these files, look for the "Unaffiliated Changes", select them, and choose "Send To Issue" then provide the correct Issue number.